# ¿Cómo validar un campo numérico al momento de pegar?

Tags: javascript

Estoy validando un input al momento de que se pegue letras, pero no he logrado hacerlo. Había un método "onpaste" que pensaba que funcionaria pero tampoco nada. Así que investigue e hice este código de aquí.

```
<input id="txtDni" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)"  maxlength="7" onkeydown="prueba()"> 

function prueba(n){
    var dni = document.getElementById("txtDni");
    var valor_dni = document.getElementById("txtDni").value;
    if(n.value != /\d/){
        n.value = "";
    }
}
```

También investigué esto y no tuve éxito

```
function prueba2(){
    var dni = document.getElementById("txtDni");
    dni.onpaste = function(){
        if(dni.value != /\d/){
            dni.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Lo único que yo quiero es cuando el usuario pegue números, este se borre inmediatamente. Sé que hay varias maneras de hacerlo, hasta me dijeron que use "onblur" y si tuve éxito, pero quiero hacerlo con lo que estoy investigando. Ya que me acuerdo cuando investigaba un proyecto en mi instituto, en la pagina de ripley para realizar compras, al momento de que te registras, estábamos haciendo pruebas para saber si estaba validado su sistema y de repente uno de mis compañeros se le ocurrió copiar y pegar, y cuando pegamos letras en un campo numérico este se elimino, o mejor dicho, se limpio. Y no permitía escribir letras. En resumen no permite escribir letras ni copiarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar un regex en tu codigo de javascript

```
 var numStr = /^\d+$/;
```

Ademas utilizar la propiedad clipboard.read Recuerda esta es para navegadores modernos y version de js actuales

```
function prueba2(){
  navigator.clipboard.readText()
   .then(text => {
   var numStr = /^\d+$/;
 if(!numStr.test(text))
    alert("El contenido a pegar no es numerico")
})
 .catch(err => {
   console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', err);
 });
}
```

Aunque preferiría que el usuario no utilizara pegar en los input, para eso deshabilitar la opción paste desde javascript

la prueba la podras ver acá: https://jsbin.com/jilemotaxi/edit?html,js,console,output