# Metodos jquery "keypress" y "blur" no funcionan

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cree 2 funciones que me estan validando un input para que no se escriba solo letras, el problema es que no sé porque no me esta ejecutando el código que estoy poniendo, aquí les dejo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function soloNumeros(e) {
        var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
        return (key >= 48 && key <= 57);
      }

      function soloPegarNumeros(n) {
        permitidos = /[^0-9.]/;
        if (permitidos.test(n.value)) {
          alert("Solo se puede ingresar numeros");
          n.value = "";
          n.focus();
        }
      }

      $("#txtDNI").on("keypress", soloNumeros(event));
      $("#txtDNI").on("blur", soloPegarNumeros(this));
      //$("#txtDNI").keypress(soloNumeros(event));
      //$("#txtDNI").blur(soloPegarNumeros(this));  
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txtDNI" MaxLength="8" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que te estas complicando un poco, si estas usando jQuery debes usar la potencia de esta librería
en tu html tienes el id del control

```
<input type="text" id="txtDNI" MaxLength="8" />
```

simplemente en el script de tu pagina colocas esto...

```
$('#txtDNI').on('input', function (event) { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

funcionando [aquí](http://jsfiddle.net/gregdorian/8uqg6pcn/8/)

Comment: Te digo algo, en primer lugar gracias, en segundo lugar "he estado estancado en esto por 8 horas buscando soluciones y nada, y eso que lo que hago es en .net que viene a ser backend en otras palabras, al final publique mi pregunta en esta web y 2 me ayudaron con mi código y nuevamente tuve que volver a ver si funcionaba, pero tu te llevar el premio de oro porque te tiraste a todos con tu única y sola linea de código, no es por exagerar pero eres lo máximo y gracias nuevamente crack :)"

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal creo que habias colocado otra pregunta parecida y que segun entendi era saber si lo que tratabas de pegar era numerico o no https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/226108/c%C3%B3mo-validar-un-campo-num%C3%A9rico-al-momento-de-pegar/226125#226125 en fin creo que se resolvió tu inquietud

Comment: Así es amigo @ger, lo que pasa es que me di cuenta que mi consulta solo era jquery, y al ver que puse .net, visual studio, etc la gente del frontend ya no entrarían de lo que estoy hablando al ver mi pregunta. Es por eso que hice otra pregunte pero solo con etiquetas del frontend y el otro lo deje ahí por si uno del backend sabia la respuesta. Por cierto, yo soy fullstack :D

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias usar el siguiente metodo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" id="txtDNI" MaxLength="8" class="solo_numeros" />
    <br><br>
</body>
<script>
   $(".solo_numeros").keypress (function (event) {
        if ((event.which < 32) || (event.which > 126)) return true; 
        return jQuery.isNumeric ($(this).val () + String.fromCharCode (event.which));
    });
    $('#txtDNI').on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
</html>
```

Si te fijas en la parte inferior valido que se escoga solo numeros en base a la clase puedes hacerlo por lo que desees id, name, class..etc.
Tambien evito el copiar, pegar o cortar en dicho input en base a su id.

[Puedes verlo aca](https://jsfiddle.net/48vj9dmg/4/)

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias, pero tengo una pregunta si no fuera molestia, ¿el "event" y "e" es lo mismo?, ¿como sabe el programa que el valor del parámetro es event?. Es por eso que yo lo he hecho así, porque para mí no tenia sentido en que momento le pasaba el el valor de parámetro. Una última preguntita, como podría hacer para que no me copie solo las letras en mi input "txtDni" ya que veo que te esta funcionando esa función.

Comment: en efecto event o e es lo mismo, puedes usar cualquiera de las dos...pero es aconsejable usar el standar que es event

Answer (score 1):

En el preciso momento que haces `soloNumeros(event)` estas ejecutando la función `soloNumeros` la cual retorna un boleano, pero el evento `keypress` lo que esta esperando es una función. Esto mismo pasa con el evento `blur` y el método `soloPegarNumeros`.

Sin alejarme tanto del contexto del código que tiene y sin realizar muchos cambios te propongo el siguiente código:

```
$("#txtDNI").on("keypress", soloNumeros);
$("#txtDNI").on("blur", function() { soloPegarNumeros(this); });
```

O también puedes envolver las dos en una función:

```
$("#txtDNI").on("keypress", function(event) { soloNumeros(event); });
$("#txtDNI").on("blur", function() { soloPegarNumeros(this); });
```